# What is the logic of this C++ Loop that converts Decimal to Binary

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am searching for codes that converts decimal to binary and i stumbled upon this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int num;
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> num;
   
    if (num > 0) {
      int i = 1;
      while (i <= num)
      i *= 2;
      i /= 2;

      do {
        if (num >= i) {
           cout << '1';
           num -= i;
        }
        else
           cout << '0';
        i /= 2;
      } while (i > 0);
      cout << "";
      
    }
    
    else
      cout << '0';
}
```

I can't seem understand the logic of this loop

```
 while (i <= num)
      i *= 2;
      i /= 2;
```

i tried to put cout in between the equations to see the process

```
 while (i <= num)
    cout << i;
    cout << "A";
      i *= 2;
    cout << i;
    cout << "B";
      i /= 2;
    cout << i;
    cout << "C";
```

but it results to 111111111111111111... and doesn't stop
can someone please explain

Comment: the loop is this only: while (i <= num) i *= 2;  you should use curly braces to enclose the statements that you want the loop to execute

Comment: As frequently seen in these questions, this loop doesn't convert decimal to binary at all. It converts binary to printable binary, or rather it would if it was written correctly. The only decimal to binary conversion here occurs at `cin >> num;`.

Comment: Take out a pencil and paper and start with and input of `10` for `num` and work though the 4-interation. It is simply converting to binary starting with `i` equal to the next power-of-two greater than `num`.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne - it is written correctly, the indention is just screwed up.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you, agreed. But it doesn't convert decimal to binary.

Comment: I get that distinction -- though I suspect it is lost on the OP. What is wanted is a binary representation of the decimal number. The computer only knows binary, so the number is already binary, but to display that representation is generally the aim. The code just outputs characters of `'0's` and `'1's` based on an algorithm -- is one way to look at it. Looping and shifting a outputting based on the bit value is another. Both just means to the learnings end.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think somebody must be teaching it this way judging by the frequency it appears here. I wish they'd stop.

Comment: Agreed. And if you think about it. It is something everybody new to programming ultimately struggles through at one time or the other. "How do I look at what the bits are in memory?" So there are generally a number of variations on this same theme time time of the year (semester `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working to understand any algorithm, you step through it with pencil-and-paper validating each step of the code. Pick a small test case, such as `10` as your input, which you know has a binary representation of `1010` and step through the four-iterations understanding what is happening.

If you do so, you will find the following:

```
    while (i <= num)            /* find next power-of-two greater than num */
        i *= 2;
```

and then it is reduced by a power-of-two to eliminate any leading zeros as output, e.g.

```
    i /= 2;                     /* divide by two, 1st power-of-two less than num */
```

This ensures `i` is the next power-of-two less than `num`. Now look at the algorithm in the `do .. while (i > 0);` loop (rearranged and indented so it makes more sense):

```
    do {                        /* loop until i <= 0 */
        if (num >= i) {         /* is num >= i? */
            std::cout << '1';   /* if so, output character '1' */
            num -= i;           /* reduce num by i */
        }
        else    /* otherwise */
            std::cout << '0';   /* output '0' character if num < i */
        i /= 2;                 /* divide i by 2 (integer division intentional) */
    } while (i > 0);
```

The algorithm is simple.

1. Iteration one - since `i` is the next power-of-two less than `num` the conditional `if (num >= i)` will test **true** guaranteeing the first character output will be `'1'`. `num` is then reduced by `i` (in the case where `num = 10;`), `i = 8` on the first iteration so `num -= i;` leaves `num = 2`. `i` is divided by `2` leaving `i = 4`.
2. Iteration two - the conditional is **false**, `'0'` is output and `i` is divided again by `2` leaving `i = 2`, so `i = num = 2`.
3. Third iteration - the conditional tests **true**, the character `'1'` is output, `num` is reduced to `0`, `i` is reduced to `1`, you loop again.
4. Fourth iteration - the conditional is **false**, `'0'` is output and `i` is reduced to zero exiting the loop.

The correct binary representation of `10` is output:

```
1010
```

If you refactor the code to eliminate the unnecessary `else` condition based on whether `num >= 0`, you simply handle the negative or zero case and return. That saves a complete level of indention throughout the code. Putting it altogether, you can rewrite the same code as:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int num, i = 1;
    std::cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> num;
    
    if (num <= 0) {
        std::cout << "0\n";
        return 0;
    }
    
    while (i <= num)            /* find next power-of-two greater than num */
        i *= 2;
    
    i /= 2;                     /* divide by two, 1st power-of-two less than num */

    do {                        /* loop until i <= 0 */
        if (num >= i) {         /* is num >= i? */
            std::cout << '1';   /* if so, output character '1' */
            num -= i;           /* reduce num by i */
        }
        else    /* otherwise */
            std::cout << '0';   /* output '0' character if num < i */
        i /= 2;                 /* divide i by 2 (integer division intentional) */
    } while (i > 0);
    
    std::cout << '\n';          /* tidy up with newline */
}
```

(**note:** See [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696) -- learning good habits is much easier than breaking bad ones later....)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/binary_conversion
Please enter a number: 10
1010
```

or

```
$ ./bin/binary_conversion
Please enter a number: 126
1111110
```

or

```
$ ./bin/binary_conversion
Please enter a number: 170
10101010
```

The code works fine. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score -1):

C++ is not Python, indentation and format literally has no effect.

```
 while (i <= num)
      i *= 2;
      i /= 2;
```

equals to

```
 while (i <= num)
 {
      i *= 2;
 }
 i /= 2;
```

That is, if `while` is not followed by a compound statement (i.e. statement block, surrounded by a pair of `{}`), then the loop body is only the first statement following `while`.

Latest version of commonly used compilers should have reported a warning about misleading indentation, it is a good habit to read every warning carefully.

Comment: No. The OP's code is correct. It wouldn't make the slightest bit of sense to put the `i /=2;` inside the loop. The loop would do nothing and never terminate. NB Latest version of what commonly-used compilers? Why should a C++ compiler care about indentation in any way?

Comment: Strange enough to see someone who didn't even read my answer to judge it. I have NEVER say the code is incorrect, it is just misleading, and you can see it confuses the question asker.

Comment: According to what presented in the question, the asker has little idea about C-style syntax and it impedes him to understand that code, so I point it out and hope it will help. Asker is not finding the fix of this code, but asking why and how it works.

Comment: "Why should a C++ compiler care about indentation in any way?" Don't ask me, ask the developers of Clang and GCC instead please @MarquisofLorne

Comment: I read it all right mate. Your 'answer', which isn't an answer, corrects a non-existent problem with indentation.